# Is there a function in java which helps to format and return the formatted date as output?

Tags: java, date, types

I'm trying to format date in java using SimpleDateFormat class. I have written a function which takes in string as a parameter and returns date as a output having the desired format. The problem arises when i try to parse the date in order to convert the string to date , the value is returned as Wed Jul 03 00:00:00 IST 2019 , instead of yyyy-MM-dd format .

```
private static final String DOB_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

public static Date convertStringToDateFormatYYYYMMDD(String date) {
        if (date != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DOB_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date parsedDate = null;
            try {
                 parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
                LOG.info("Date formated " + parsedDate);
                return parsedDate;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                LOG.info("Date Parsing Issue - date :" + date);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The result value should be returned as  yyyy-MM-dd, instead of Wed Jul 03 00:00:00 IST 2019

Comment: a Date itself is not formatted. return a formatted String containing the information.

Comment: Err, `DateFormat`? `SimpleDateFormat`? What does [tag:casting] have to do with it?

Comment: The return type cannot be changed as it would have a regressive impact on other functions in the codebase.

Comment: @ShreyashSharma ok, but your question makes no sense. `Date`s are not formatted, as Stultuske said. You need to format it at the point where you store/display it.

Comment: You might want to read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: will change the function, Thank you.

Comment: While it may not be an option for you, for other readers: Use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`. First, it does print in yyyy-mm-dd format as you want. Second, it's the modern and much better designed class. `Date` is poorly designed and long outdated. Third, `LocalDate` represents a date without time of day and thus matches your apparent need much more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

> I'm trying to format date in java using SimpleDateFormat class.

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes, with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

## ISO 8601

> DOB_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd"

That format happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

The *java.time* classes comply with the standard as well, using those formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

```
String input = "2019-01-23" ; // January 23, 2019
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
```

## Text has formats, not date-time objects

You Question also says:

> value is returned as Wed Jul 03 00:00:00 IST 2019 , instead of yyyy-MM-dd format .

Be clear that date-time objects do not have a “format”. Only text strings have a format. A date-time object is *not* a text string. A date-time object parses a text string to generate a date-time value, and a date-time object can generate text representing its date-time value. But the date-time object and the text are distinct and separate from one another.

[image: diagram showing formatted input text being parsed as date-time object without any concept of "formatting", and then generating formatted output text.]

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

> Date parsedDate = null;

The terrible `java.util.Date` class represents a date with time-of-day in UTC (an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds). But you want only a date, without the time-of-day and without an offset or time zone. So square peg, round hole. Instead, use appropriate types. And stop using those legacy date-time classes; use only *java.time* classes.

## Generating text

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = localDate.toString() ;
```

> 2019-01-23

To generate a string automatically-localized:

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = localDate.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com.](https://ideone.com/eZyvu4)

> 23 janv. 2019

Answer (score 0):

Date object is not formatted itself. You can return a formatted String containing the information.